# Дочерний блок выходит за родительский блок

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть `header`, высота `100vh`, внутри него есть блок `offset` с двумя блоками и кнопкой. При размере экрана в `320 px` этот блок съезжает вниз, выходя за родительский блок.

По какой причине ?

```css
.header{
 padding-top: 30px;
 background: #000 url(../img/header-background.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100vh;
}

.logo{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 29px;
    padding-right: 23px;
}

.phone{
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.phone__icon{
 padding-right: 7px;
 color: #bec8c8;
}

.menu{
 list-style: none; 
 justify-content:flex-end;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 12px;
 padding-left: 0;
 width: 585px;
}

.menu__item{
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 
}

.menu__item a{
 padding: 10px;
 color: #b3bfbf;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-right: 26px;
}

.menu__item a:hover{
 background-color: #6a7f80;
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.offset{
 margin-top: 236px;
}

.offset__title{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 38px;
 color: #fff;
}

.offset__text{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 width: 513px;
}

.offset__btn{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #6fb048;
 width: 186px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 19px 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.offset__btn:hover{
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #5a8f3a;
}

.features{
 padding-top: 95px;
}

.title__main{
 font-size: 32px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #0f5f5c;
 text-align: center;
}

.title__main:after{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 width: 65px;
 height: 1px;
 background-color: #6fb048;
 margin: 18px auto;
}

.title__text{
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 color: #83a7a5;
 text-align: center;
 width: 450px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.feature{
 padding-top: 68px;
 padding-bottom: 175px;
}

.feature__title{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #0f5f5c;
 padding-top: 30px;
}

.feature__text{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #83a7a5;
 line-height: 22px;
 width: 335px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
          <div class="logo">
            WAPIK
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-2 mt-auto mb-auto col-sm-6">
            <div class="phone">
              <i class="fas fa-phone-alt phone__icon"></i>+62 202 555 0117
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 ml-auto p-0">
            <nav>
              <ul class="menu d-flex">
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">pricing</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="offset">
            <h1 class="offset__title">Welcome to Wapik</h1>
            <p class="offset__text">Wapik is multipurpose template, with modern and smart design. Wapik is perfect template for you!</p>
            <a href="#" class="offset__btn">LEARN MORE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </header>
   <section class="features">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
           <div class="features__title">
             <h2 class="title__main">Best of our features</h2>
             <p class="title__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
             Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4">
           <div class="feature text-center">
             <img src="img/icon1.png" alt="icon">
             <div class="feature__block">
               <h3 class="feature__title">
                lonicons
              </h3>
              <p class="feature__text">
               Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem.
             </p>
           </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4">
           <div class="feature text-center">
             <img src="img/icon2.png" alt="icon">
             <div class="feature__block">
               <h3 class="feature__title">
                Creative Design
              </h3>
              <p class="feature__text">
               Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.
             </p>
           </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4">
           <div class="feature text-center">
             <img src="img/icon3.png" alt="icon">
             <div class="feature__block">
               <h3 class="feature__title">
                Photoshop and Sketch
              </h3>
              <p class="feature__text">
               Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.
             </p>
           </div>
         </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в класс `.header` дополнительно `width: 100%;`

Comment: ничего не дало.